# How to set the text direction in WebView to RTL (Right To Left)? [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, right-to-left, left-to-right

When I log in to the app, I see the Webview starting from left to right.

I tried to change through the left-to-right management panel - it didn't work for me.
I tried some guides and it also did not work for me.

Anyone know where I'm supposed to do this from? From the website files or through Android Studio? And if so, how exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I think by adding the following css code in your website's **<style>** tag you can achieve right to left direction.

```
 body { direction: rtl; }
```

Or change your <html> tag into

```
 <html dir="rtl">
```

If it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately not, or I'm not doing it right - is there a way maybe to contact you? @Zborkala

Comment: mail me @ gzubsite@gmail.com